# Android Studio won't start

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm not able to start Android Studio, it return immediately this error:

```
    Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.picocontainer.MutablePicoContainer.registerComponentInstance(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/picocontainer/ComponentAdapter;
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.bootstrapPicoContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.java:349)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.bootstrapPicoContainer(ApplicationImpl.java:167)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.<init>(ComponentManagerImpl.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.<init>(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:27)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.<init>(ApplicationImpl.java:191)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ex.ApplicationManagerEx.createApplication(ApplicationManagerEx.java:45)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.<init>(IdeaApplication.java:112)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:47)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

I'm using Mac OS X 10.10.3 and Java 1.8.0_25.

How I can solve this? I'm really not idea what is the problem!
Thank you for your help!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a lot of Android Studio issues can be fixed by simply re-installing the program. Sometimes jar files and other directories get messed up along the way.

I would first try just reinstalling Android studio, and go from there.

Comment: I have already tried to reinstall the IDE (using the same dmg file) but the result is the same.
Reading this page [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) I have also installed IntelliJ IDEA but when I start it the message is the same!
Now I have download the software from here: [link](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other)